# Tokenize string and know which part of delimiter grabbed

Tags: php, token, tokenize

I like to tokenize a string with the `strtok()` function of PHP and like to know which part of the delimiter grabbed the current token.

So here is an example:

```
#my comment
something: one, two, three
```

If I use now:

```
$token = strtok($string, '#:,' . PHP_EOL);
```

I get `my comment` as first token because the `#` and `new line` tokenized it. So is there now a possibility to get the starting and ending delimiter of the current token?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a way to include delimiters because they have some *special syntax* meaning - then you should use syntax tools. [`strtok()`](http://php.net/strtok) won't differ your delimiters because it's not the intention of this function.

Instead you may try to use [`token_get_all()`](http://php.net/token_get_all):

```
$string = '#my comment
something: one, two, three';
//note that <?php is needed to make it parse PHP syntax:
$result = token_get_all('<?php '.$string);
```

-it will parse syntax and split lexems into resulting array (so you'll get your comment and your pieces of string together with array members that correspond such things as `:`, `,` e t.c.).

Comment: Yet in the same time it will do the work (you only need to specify desired output - so group delimiters with lexems properly)

Comment: Strange... why does this work? It's not valid PHP at all... but this is only a simple example. It will get more complex in future use.

Comment: Because this function is not an _interpreter_ it's just _scanner_ (i.e. it will scan for lexem). It isn't aware about what is valid PHP code.

Comment: Alright. And can I somehow set my own Lexer mapping for the function?

Comment: Wow.. that's really interesting/useful. Never knew about that functionality. And, using `token_get_all()` and `token_name()` it would be really easy to filter out the tokens you want to throw away; e.g: `T_COMMENT`. I just learned something this morning :)

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER what do you mean "your own mapping"? You may use standard lexem indexes (they would be keys) and then re-name as you wish

Comment: I mean this list here: http://ch1.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php is for PHP can I write my own and use it with `token_get_all()`?

Comment: You can. Use the function, then loop resulting array and grab lexems with keys. Then change lexem names as you wish. But if you want somehow to define your own lexem - then it won't work (but I can't imagine what should be the thing that will not be grabbed by this function in normal case)